# Does Power BI Desktop have any developer option?

Tags: typescript, plugins, powerbi, visualization

Power BI Web have an option of developer tool. Is anything like that for Power BI Desktop? So that I can able to load a web page inside Power BI Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom visual, such as [HTML Viewer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104381214?flightCodes=PandaDocToCRM) which will render html within a Power BI report.

You can then use an iframe to display your chosen webpage:

```
<iframe src='https://stackoverflow.com'></iframe>
```

Comment: I am not getting any option to insert this <iframe src='https://stackoverflow.com'></iframe> inside Power BI Desktop HTML Viewer.

Comment: Pass that as your data, to the visualisation... See https://powerpivotpro.com/2018/11/dynamically-embedding-web-pages-in-power-bi/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does have Developer options
follow this link it will show you steps to follow on how to enable it. Read the instructions properly

To enable Developer mode, follow these steps:

1. Open Power BI Desktop.
2. Select File > Options and settings.
3. Select Options.
4. In the Options window, from the CURRENT FILE list, select Report settings.
5. In Developer Mode, select the Turn on developer mode for this session option

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/submission-testing